# Issue with GLBatch from OpenGL Superbible

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut, access-violation

Looking around the internet, it seems quite a few people have had this problem, but there have been no definitive solutions to it. For those who have read the 'OpenGL Superbible' (5th edition) - or those who haven't - the `GLBatch` class seems to have issues handing geometry. Here is a snippet of code using the `GLTools` library from the book:

```
triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);

triangleBatch.Color4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
triangleBatch.Vertex3f(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

triangleBatch.Color4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
triangleBatch.Vertex3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

triangleBatch.Color4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
triangleBatch.Vertex3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

triangleBatch.End();
```

Using OpenGL 2.1, which is the default on the computer I am using (Mac OSX running Mountain Lion, V. 10.8.5), this code runs fine. But as soon as I set `GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE` as an argument for `glutInitDisplayMode` I get the error `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file` and `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)` at the line `triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);`.

I have opened `GLBatch.cpp` and commented out the entire `GLBatch::Begin` function but I still receive the same error. I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening. The authors of the book obviously know the core profile is needed to access features of OpeGL such as FBOs, modern GLSL, etc. So why can't I get such simple code to work?

Comment: As a side note not related to your error, *"The authors of the book obviously know the core profile is needed to access features of OpenGL such as FBOs, modern GLSL"* - No, the core profile is not *needed* to access those features.

Comment: @ChristianRau Ok, perhaps needed was not the word to use there. Though FBOs, to my knowledge, can only be used as an extension in the compatibility profile. And as for GLSL, I was under the impression that many features are only available in more modern versions(1.3 and upwards) such as the key words 'in' and 'out.'

Comment: Many features are only available in newer versions, that's of course true. But this doesn't have anything to do with the profiles. OpenGL version 4.4 (for example) has all the modern features in each profile, It's just that the compatibility profile has the old and deprecated stuff *in addition* to the new stuff. So *"Though FBOs, to my knowledge, can only be used as an extension in the compatibility profile."* - No.

Comment: @ChristianRau Ah, I actually didn't know that. I guess that's just being new and unknowledgeable in the area. In relation to the question, then, that makes even less sense as new additions to OpenGL will only work if I set GLUT to use the core profile. Strange....